# What are the different ways to create grayscale effect and the principal behind?

Tags: css

I'm trying to learn HTML and CSS. Yesterday night, when I was trying new things I came across a problem. I added a background image and wanted to make it black and white. It shows the image but its in colors. It didn't work however I tried. I'm out of answer at the moment. Thanks in advance.

```css
body {
  background-image: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/04/03/15/27/flower-meadow-4999277_1280.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}

#logo {
  font-family: 'Aladin', cursive;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left: 75px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Testing 1-2-3</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/master.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Aladin&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="logo">
      VolviX
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've fixed your snippet with simongcc's picture. Next time please check that your snippet actually works.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I have updated the answer. I think it the question does not exactly duplicated since what the user would like to know is not explained in other posts. I have added those explanation to the answer. If the title change a bit like "what is different ways to create grayscale effect and the principal behind" would make it more unique question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>It is because css [greyscale()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/grayscale) is for filtering image loaded with `<img>`.</strike> Updated as follow, it does WORK for CSS background except HTML and Body tag. So I try to wrap up all the situations here AFAIK.

#### Situation 1 - background image + blend

For background image, you need to apply other tricks like [`background-blend-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-blend-mode) property. You may refer some example online such as [this](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/filter/)

```
body {
      background-image: linear-gradient(black, black), url(../img/ejager.jpg);
      background-size: cover;
      background-blend-mode: saturation;
}
```

Since your image is relative, so I use free online image as example.

```css
body {
       /* free image from https://pixabay.com/photos/flower-meadow-daisy-nature-flowers-4999277/ */
        background-image:  url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/04/03/15/27/flower-meadow-4999277_1280.jpg), linear-gradient(black, black);
        background-size: cover;
        background-blend-mode: saturation;
}
```

The principal behind this method:

> The `background-blend-mode` CSS property sets how an element's background images should blend with each other and with the element's background color.

[background-image property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image) support multiple background images since quite a long time.

The above example could be replaced with a normal black background image. For convenient sake, the example use this to create a black background.

> The linear-gradient() CSS function creates an image consisting of a progressive transition between two or more colors along a straight line. Its result is an object of the  data type, which is a special kind of .

As a result, it could be seen as a black background image with another image together and then use the blend filter to blend their saturation together.
According to the [blend definition](https://www.w3.org/TR/compositing-1/#blendingsaturation).

> Creates a color with the saturation of the source color and the hue and luminosity of the backdrop color. Painting with this mode in an area of the backdrop that is a pure gray (no saturation) produces no change.

In this case, `the saturation of the source color` is `the saturation of black` and `the hue and luminosity of the backdrop color` (the flower image)

It then preserves the flower image but with black and white effect.

#### Situation 2 - filter a image tag

Here is example of greyscale for image tag

```css
img {
     filter: grayscale(1);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/04/03/15/27/flower-meadow-4999277_1280.jpg" alt="">
```

Edited: After a thorough test with different filters. There is a few characteristic found as follow.

#### Situation 3 - Apply filter to html and body tag.

Filter is not working for background-image in HTML or Body tag.
However, it works if you setup the background image in a psuedo element.

- html, Safari works, FF, Chrome doesn't
- body, Safari, FF, Chrome doesn't
- html::before - before all content inside html
- html::after - theoretically, it works but it should be out of the boundary, although ::after exists in DOM, nothing is displayed.
- body::before - before all content of body
- body::after - after all content of body

So, as a cross browser solution, to apply filter to body, `body::before` is sensible according to [support of pseudo element across different browsers](https://caniuse.com/#search=%3A%3Abefore).

```css
body::before {
  /* positioning */
  content: ' ';
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  
  background-image: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/04/03/15/27/flower-meadow-4999277_1280.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  filter: grayscale(1);
}
```

Related posts: [about not working in body tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42400970/css-filter-not-working-on-body-in-chrome-firefox), it may be a bug because it behave inconsistently across different browsers.

#### Situation 4 - Apply filter to elements other than html and body

It works without issues.

```css
#content {
    background-image: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/04/03/15/27/flower-meadow-4999277_1280.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    
    filter: grayscale(1);
}

body, html, #content {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
```

Appendix

[CSS Filter Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function)
[How to apply post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20039765/how-to-apply-a-css-filter-to-a-background-image)
[Apply to partial element post 1](https://www.w3.org/TR/filter-effects-1/#funcdef-filter-grayscale)

Comment: It doesn't work if you don't put "linear-gradient(black, black)". Could you please explain that as well?

Comment: @VolviX I have updated the answer for everything I know so far.

Comment: @VolviX Sorry that I find a typo in the solutions, the cross browser solution of body should be `body::before` instead of after because if using after, it will place after everything in the body.